# My custom ViewGroup doesn't scroll inside a ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, viewgroup

I've extended ViewGroup. I put my custom ViewGroup into a ScrollView, dynamically add a bunch of content and it doesn't scroll. The content that flows off the screen is not viewable.
In the below xml file, if I remove the Scrollview:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myalltags_scrollview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

it can work.

What am I missing? How can I allow my ViewGroup to be compatible with ScrollView?

```
package com.android.picker;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyViewGroup extends ViewGroup {
    private final static String TAG = "MyViewGroup";

    public final static int VIEW_MARGIN=2;
    private final static int MAX_TAG_LINES=3;
    private Button lastMoreButton;
    public int totalHeight=0;

    public MyViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.i(TAG,"myViewgroup");
    }

    public void fullTags(Context context,List<String> rs,Button button){
        for(String s:rs){
           Button v=new Button(context);
           v.setText(s);
           this.addView(v);
        };
        if(button!=null){
            this.addView(button);
            this.lastMoreButton=button;
        }
    }

    public void fullTags(Context context,List<String> rs){
        this.fullTags(context,rs,null);
    }

    public MyViewGroup(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context,attributeSet);
        Log.i(TAG,"myViewgroupattributeSet");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Log.d(TAG, "widthMeasureSpec = "+widthMeasureSpec+" heightMeasureSpec"+heightMeasureSpec);

        for (int index = 0; index < getChildCount(); index++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(index);
            // measure
            child.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight+=child.getMeasuredHeight();            
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        Log.d(TAG, "changed = "+arg0+" left = "+l+" top = "+t+" right = "+r+" botom = "+b);
        final int count = getChildCount();
        int row=0;// which row lay you view relative to parent
        int lengthX=l;    // right position of child relative to parent
        int lengthY=t;    // bottom position of child relative to parent
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){            
            final View child = this.getChildAt(i);
            Log.i("aa",((Button)child).getText().toString());
            int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            lengthX+=width+VIEW_MARGIN;
            //if it can't drawing on a same line , skip to next line
            if(lengthX>r){
                lengthX=width+VIEW_MARGIN+l;
                row++;
            }
            lengthY=row*(height+VIEW_MARGIN)+VIEW_MARGIN+height+t;

            child.layout(lengthX-width, lengthY-height, lengthX, lengthY);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myalltags_scrollview" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">  
        <com.android.picker.MyViewGroup android:id="@+id/myalltags"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </com.android.picker.MyViewGroup> 
   </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
package com.android.picker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyTagsDialog extends Dialog{
    private Context context;
    private MyViewGroup myAllTagsView;

    public MyTagsDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
        this.setContentView(R.layout.mytagslayout);
        initView();
        initData();
    }

    private void initData() {
        List<String> rs=new ArrayList<String>();
        rs.add("test1"); 
        rs.add("test2"); 
        rs.add("test3"); 
        rs.add("test4"); 
        rs.add("test5"); 
        rs.add("test6"); 
        rs.add("test7"); 
        rs.add("test8"); 
        rs.add("test9"); 
        rs.add("test10"); 
        rs.add("test11"); 
        rs.add("test12"); 

        myAllTagsView.fullTags(context,rs);
        //    MyViewGroupPackage mypackages=new MyViewGroupPackage();
        //    mypackages.hasmore=true;
        //    mypackages.imems=rs;
    //        myAllTagsView.fullTags(context, rs);
    //        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myAllTagsView.getLayoutParams();  
    //        params.height = myAllTagsView.totalHeight + 100;
    //        Log.i("cccc",""+params.height);
    //        myAllTagsView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private void initView() {
        myAllTagsView=(MyViewGroup)this.findViewById(R.id.myalltags);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    import android.content.Context;

    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    /**
     *
     * @author RAW
     */
    public class FlowLayout extends ViewGroup {
        private final static int PAD_H = 2, PAD_V = 2; // Space between child views.
        private int mHeight;

        public FlowLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            assert (MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec) != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
            final int count = getChildCount();
            int xpos = getPaddingLeft();
            int ypos = getPaddingTop();
            int childHeightMeasureSpec;
            if(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
                childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            else
                childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            mHeight = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final View child = getChildAt(i);
                if(child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                    child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), childHeightMeasureSpec);
                    final int childw = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                    mHeight = Math.max(mHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight() + PAD_V);
                    if(xpos + childw > width) {
                        xpos = getPaddingLeft();
                        ypos += mHeight;
                    }
                    xpos += childw + PAD_H;
                }
            }
            if(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
                height = ypos + mHeight;
            } else if(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                if(ypos + mHeight < height) {
                    height = ypos + mHeight;
                }
            }
            height += 5; // Fudge to avoid clipping bottom of last row.
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } // end onMeasure()

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            final int width = r - l;
            int xpos = getPaddingLeft();
            int ypos = getPaddingTop();
            for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                final View child = getChildAt(i);
                if(child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                    final int childw = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                    final int childh = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                    if(xpos + childw > width) {
                        xpos = getPaddingLeft();
                        ypos += mHeight;
                    }
                    child.layout(xpos, ypos, xpos + childw, ypos + childh);
                    xpos += childw + PAD_H;
                }
            }
        } // end onLayout()
    }

        enter code here


******************************************************************************************

<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

           <com.goumin.tuan.view.FlowLayout
              android:id="@+id/goods_page_goods_level1_ll"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
           </com.goumin.tuan.view.FlowLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <com.goumin.tuan.view.FlowLayout
                            android:id="@+id/goods_page_goods_level1_ll"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        </com.goumin.tuan.view.FlowLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

```
try to change you  layout  like below  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Linearlayout
        android:id="@+id/myalltags_scrollview" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">  
        <com.android.picker.MyViewGroup android:id="@+id/myalltags"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </com.android.picker.MyViewGroup> 
   </Linearlayout>

</<ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks for your answering,but the Viewgroup cannot be showed when i updated your code.when i changed the xml like this,<code>
    <Linearlayout
        android:id="@+id/myalltags_scrollview" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">  
        <com.android.picker.MyViewGroup android:id="@+id/myalltags"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"> <!--must be specified-->
        </com.android.picker.MyViewGroup> 
   </Linearlayout></code>